# Does the ToString() method of the following concrete exception types yield sensitive data?

Tags: c#, security, exception, error-logging

Despite searching exhaustively, I couldn´t find a discussion of the mentioned question. Please point me to the question if there´s any.

Now to my question. I´d like to log the output of the `ToString()` method of the following  concrete exceptions (they aren´t custom exceptions, i.e., I didn´t write them myself) into a file:

- ArgumentNullException
- System.Exception itself
- SecurityTokenException and exceptions that inherit from SecurityTokenException (e.g.,
  SecurityTokenExpiredException)

Is it save to do so, i.e., doesn´t `ToString()` return senstive data that might have caused the exception in the first place?

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-exception-tostring), `System.Exception.ToString()` returns the following output:

> The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class
> that threw the current exception, the message, the result of calling
> ToString on the inner exception, and the result of calling
> Environment.StackTrace. If any of these members is null, its value is
> not included in the returned string.

Examining the [Environment.Stacktrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=net-6.0) yields (if I understood it correctly) the following information:

- StackTrace doesn´t contain senstive data (only method parameter names not their values)
- Name of the class is fine (no senstive data here!)
- InnerEception.ToString() follows the definition of `ToString()` above. Hence, it should be fine too.

Does the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.message?view=net-6.0) property of the mentioned exceptions yield senstive data (e.g., parameter values, content of JwtSecurityToken etc.)? Can the pure unchanged output of the message proeprty be logged savely (I know there´s encryption but independent of that)?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this. All exceptions inherit from `System.Exception`. The Message contents depend on the code that raised the exception. If someone wrote a `throw new Exception(jwt);` then yes, the exception will include the JWT. So don't write such code

Comment: There isn't a single definition of "sensitive data".

Comment: The stacktrace shows details about your code (a method chain), which *may* expose parts of your application that you would rather keep hidden

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the moment. You just described my concern. What if some of the mentioned exceptions would include such data? Are there any other thoughts about this?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever By "sensitive data" I mean personal information of a user (name, birthdate, NO passwords but GDPR compliant)

Comment: As Panagiotis said, it depends entirely on the specific exception and how it was thrown. If you created a custom exception that includes lots of confidential information when you call `.ToString()` then yes, confidential information would be logged. If a library you're passing such data through has an exception that does that, it's the same story.

Comment: @IRobot you misunderstood what I wrote. It's not the exceptions, it's the code that raises them. It's no different than writing sensitive data to a file. You won't solve this problem by asking whether `File.WriteAllText` will write sensitive data. You'll solve it by making sure the sensitive data isn't emitted in the first place.

Comment: Besides, it's more likely headers and JWTs will end up in the web server's request log, perhaps because someone decided to just log everything. It's highly unlikely a developer would explicitly write the code to include headers and tokens in an *exception*.

Comment: Any part of your code or of your dependencies could throw an Exeption using a message containing sensitive informations. You have no way to know in advance. You should assume the answer is yes. Exception messages could include sensitive information

Comment: Thank you for your great and helpful input! I am quite new to this. So please apologize the following question ;)

Despite everyone´s good input, I´d like to accept the comment(s) of @PanagiotisKanavos as an answer to my question, because it was the first answer. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: One common leak to be aware of is that if you are using sensitive info in JSON or XML, an exception while deserializing it could leak info, as the deserializing code will return info on piece of text was failing